# Acumatica- Update Sales Order from Purchase Order

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to update a custom field on the SOLine (UsrPOPromisedDate) when the POLine promised date is changed. Below is my graph extension, however SOLine is always null.
When I convert the BQL to T-SQL, I get the expected results returned.  Why is my view always returning a null value?

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.KWW.MyProject.DAC;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace MyProject.Graph
{
    public class POOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
    {
        public PXSelectJoin<
            SOLine,
            InnerJoin<SOLineSplit,
                On<SOLineSplit.orderType, Equal<SOLine.orderType>,
                And<SOLineSplit.orderNbr, Equal<SOLine.orderNbr>,
                And<SOLineSplit.lineNbr, Equal<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>,
            Where<SOLineSplit.pOType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>,
                And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderNbr>>,
                And<SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr, Equal<Current<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>>
            SalesOrderLine;

        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<POLine, POLine.promisedDate> eventHandler, PXFieldUpdated baseHandler)
        {
            baseHandler?.Invoke(eventHandler.Cache, eventHandler.Args);

            POLine pOLine = eventHandler.Row;
            if (pOLine is null) return;

            SOLine sOLine = SalesOrderLine.Current;
            SOLineExtension sOLineExtension = sOLine.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>();

            if (sOLine is null || sOLineExtension is null) return;

            sOLineExtension.UsrPOPromisedDate = pOLine.PromisedDate;
            SalesOrderLine.Update(sOLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help?: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean SalesOrderLine.Current is null, I don't believe the Current field is populated by default unless the user has selected a specific record within the view(or you manually set it).

If you are just trying to get the records within the view you would need to use SalesOrderLine.Select().

```csharp
    foreach(SOLine line in SalesOrderLine.Select()){ 
         //Do Something Here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mistake in your code.

```
                And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>,
```

Comment: Yes you are correct there.  This unfortunately isn't the answer.  I went through several iterations of the view, and I must have made this mistake on this one.  The SalesOrderLine is still always null.

Comment: I would suggest changing your Where statement to this  Where<SOLineSplit.pOType, Equal<Current<POOrder.orderType>>,
                And<SOLineSplit.pONbr, Equal<Current<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>

Comment: I would still need to join on SOLineSplit.pOLineNbr = SOLine.LineNbr

Comment: You don't need to have a 1:1. sync here.  You need a SOLine Cache to perform operations.  You could have a vanilla PXSelect<SOLine>SalesOrderLines view.  The cache would contain the lines in question, you would either search the view for the correct soline or do a PXSelect<SOLine> search in the code.  Then update the line and update the cache with the updated line object.  When the save button is pushed, the updated lines would be saved back to the db.